# Programmatically log in to Spring Security during initialization of database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security and  have method like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
void createUser(..)

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
void createDepartment(..)

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
void createProject(..)
```

Only users with role ADMIN are allowed to execute the methods. Inside the method the executing admin (current logged in user) will be added as creator to the new record.

Problem:
At first start of the app when the database is empty, I want to create default users / departments / projects.

```
private void init() {
  createUser("admin", "admin");
  createProject("defaultProject");
  ..
}
```

I thought about having some system user with admin role who should execute init().
How can I log in as that system user programmaticaly just for executing init()?

Thanks!

PS: Skipping @PreAuthorize check is not enough since I need a logged in user inside those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom `Authentication` with right role to `SecurityContextHolder` before `init`. Something like

```
protected void setSecurityContext() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
        User user = new User("userName", null, null);

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
        AnonymousAuthenticationToken anonymousAuthenticationToken = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("test", user, grantedAuthorities);
        securityContext.setAuthentication(anonymousAuthenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

        // init method
        //...


        // don't forget to clear context
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Could you also explain the "test" argument in AnonymousAuthenticationToken. I don't understand the explanation in javadoc.

Parameters:
key - to identify if this object made by an authorised client

Comment: here is more about the [key](http://springcert.sourceforge.net/sec-3/anonymous.html#ftn.d4e1786), I think that's not the point, you can set any authenticated authentication in SecurityContextHolder, e.g `UsernamePasswordAuthentication`

Answer (score 1):

If the `init()` method belongs to the same class as `createUser()` and `createProject()` you don't need be authenticated user at all because `@PreAuthorize` checks won't work.

If the `init()` method inside another class then you can create another method in the class with `createUser()` and invoke it from the `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing all the details about your app. Typically bootstrapping database can be done using database migration tools like liquibase.

If you cannot leverage that you can potentially have listener configured to listen to "ContextStartedEvent". That way you can set securityContext in that class and not have to worry about re-use, etc.

Typically using migration tool is better approach as it would work even if you have multiple instances of the application or if you end up re-starting the service multiple times you don't need custom logic.